# Clearance gem redirect issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clearance

Hello I'am using clearance gem for user authentication.

So far everything works perfect, but I'am confused why even after setting the root routes for my pages index view, it still redirects me to the sign_in page of clearance gem.

I have looked at github documentation notes, and it list no other work around for this. I'am doing something wrong?

Here is what my routes.rb file looks like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

resources :passwords, controller: "clearance/passwords", only: 
[:create, :new]
resource :session, controller: "clearance/sessions", only: [:create]

resources :users, controller: "clearance/users", only: [:create] do
resource :password,
  controller: "clearance/passwords",
  only: [:create, :edit, :update]
end

get "/sign_in" => "clearance/sessions#new", as: "sign_in"
delete "/sign_out" => "clearance/sessions#destroy", as: "sign_out"
get "/sign_up" => "clearance/users#new", as: "sign_up"


root 'pages#index'
# For details on the DSL available within this file, see 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Comment: share your terminal screen. And delete your history from browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the clearance `require_login` before_action must be active for that route. Did you add that before action to application controller? Does PagesController inherit from ApplicationCobtroller? If so, you need to add `skip_before_action :require_login` to your pages controller. Perhaps scoped to the particular pages controller action you want unprotected.

Comment: require_login was added to my application controller, and the pages controller inherited from that class; however, "skip_before_action :require_login" solved the problem. Thanks a lot.